# Firefox cancels downloads before they begin

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, permissions, download

About a week ago, I noticed that a download from Firefox didn't complete.  I looked at the download dialog and the download had been cancelled.  I clicked the download and restarted it; it seemed to start but then I couldn't open the file.

I then copied the download link into Chrome and it worked as normal.  I went to the file and double clicked it but my system told me I didn't have permissions to open the file.  I right clicked and went to Properties and there was a button at the bottom called "Unblock" - I unblocked the file and it then worked as normal.

For the last week or so, I have been downloading files with this technique but it's a pain.  What is going on here?  I clicked around in Firefox options and found no sign of a setting that needs my attention.  Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mozilla's article [Enable downloads blocked by Security Zone Policy](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Unable%2Bto%2Bdownload%2Bor%2Bsave%2Bfiles#Enable_downloads_blocked_by_Security_Zone_Policy) might have an explanation for the problem:

> Downloading an executable file (e.g.,
>   an .exe or .msi file) may fail, with
>   the Downloads window showing Canceled
>   under the file name.
>
> This happens because Firefox honors
>   your Windows security settings for
>   downloading applications and other
>   potentially unsafe files from the
>   Internet.

Evidently, Chrome doesn't care about the Windows security setting, but Firefox does.

The solutions proposed are:

> A. Bypass Windows Security Policy check
>
> You can add the preference, browser.download.manager.skipWinSecurityPolicyChecks and set it to true. This will bypass the Windows Security Policy.
>
> B. Reset system Internet Security settings
>
> You can [reset your system Internet security settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737) in Internet Explorer.

Or for a less-destructive version of solution B, just go into Control Panel -> Internet Properties -> Security Tab, scroll down to
Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains,
then change it from "Denied" to "Prompt".

Comment: I ended up having to reset the security settings.  Firefox 3.6 cannot be fixed with the fix A, unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

Did you get any errors from your Error Console (Ctrl + Shift + J) ?
Have you installed a new add-on / application recently?

Comment: No errors pertaining to this...

Answer (score 1):

For Windows XP:

Start > Run > type:

```
regsvr32.exe urlmon.dll
```

Once registered, the download problem should get solved. This should also work for Windows Vista and Windows 7.